# text on the right of the pic, js

Tags: javascript

I have a div and inside that div i have a pic and a text. Right now text goes at the bottom of the pic and if the text is large then we cannot see the whole text , what i want is pic on the left side and text on the right side of the pic and everything should fit inside the broder, please have a look at the pic for more info , any help will be highly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Please show your HTML and your attempted CSS; please see the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines for what's expected of a question.

Comment: This is ***really easy*** to research yourself. There are lots and lots of resources on the web dedicated to basic layout

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `float: left` for the image may be what you need

https://jsfiddle.net/1kvykb18/

Comment: this si awesome thx for great help. one more question the text are too close to image is there anyway to create little distance to make it look neat and clean

Comment: You can set `margin: right` of the image to achive that. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/1kvykb18/1/

Answer (score 2):

Float the image to left. In your css:

```
img{float: left;}
```

Comment: image is perfect, i just needa help on my text, right now its at the bottom i need to align it to the right side;

Comment: great Regis finally working , small question the text are too close to image and doesnt look good is there anyway to keep lil distance between image and text

Comment: Set a margin for the image.

Answer (score 1):

For designing and DOM styling issue, you have to choose CSS tag. There I tried to do this by seeing your image try this code instead. For float your image you can only use `float: left` or you can try this code.

```
HTML :

<div class="post-container">
    <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
    <div class="post-thumb"><img src="your image url"/></div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <p>this is a test this is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a testthis is a test </p></div>
</div>

CSS:

.post-container {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    border: 1px solid #333;
    overflow: auto
}
.post-thumb {
    float: left
}
.post-thumb img {
    display: block
    height : 200px;width:200px;
}
.post-content {
    margin-left: 210px
}
.post-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 9px;
    background: #ccc
}
```